# map Functor over a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor, map-function

bit confused. `fmap` sounds like it can `map` all over a list of `Maybe`'s, but I can't get it to work if I use e.g. `fApplyFunctor = (+1) <$> [Just 1, Just 2]`.

What seems to work perfectly fine is: `map ((+1) <$>) [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3]`. This seems to be overkill in that sense that I recall `fmap` could do that by itself already...

Comment: define `(<<$>>) = fmap . fmap`, then use `(+1) <<$>> [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3]`. also, `(<<<$>>>) = fmap . fmap . fmap` for `(+1) <<<$>>> Right [Just 1, Just 2, Just 3]` etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No `fmap` means you can *map* over an arbitrary `Functor` type (well think about it for now as a collection), but you only do this *one "functor level"* deep. In case you `fmap` with a list, it is exactly equivalent to `map`.

`fmap` however is defined over all sorts of `Functor`s, like lists, `Maybe`s, etc. Here you can thus `fmap` in the `fmap` to map over *two* levels:

```
fApplyFunctor = fmap (fmap (+1)) [Just 1, Just 2]
```

This will then result in:

```
Prelude> fmap (fmap (+1)) [Just 1, Just 2]
[Just 2,Just 3]
Prelude> (fmap (+1)) <$> [Just 1, Just 2]
[Just 2,Just 3]
Prelude> ((+1) <$>) <$> [Just 1, Just 2]
[Just 2,Just 3]
```

**EDIT**: like [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104252/map-functor-over-a-list-in-haskell/53104305?noredirect=1#comment93103967_53104305) says, there exists a data type [**`Compose`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) which works over two (or more if you *cascade*) `Functor`s and thus allows us to `fmap` two levels deep. This is implemented like:

> ```
> newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
>
> instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
>     fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)
> ```

so here we again perform an `fmap` on two levels:

```
Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> getCompose ((+1) <$> Compose [Just 1, Just 2])
[Just 2,Just 3]
```

But as you see it requires some syntax to first wrap the data in a `Compose`, and then to later "unwrap" it out of the `Compose`, so this requires some extra work as well.

Comment: There is also `(+1) <$> Compose [Just 1, Just 2]`. But in every real-life case I've come across, it's been way syntactically heavier to bring in `Compose` than to just type `fmap` twice, so... +1 on this answer from me. =)

Comment: @DanielWagner: thanks. Did not know about the `Compose`, added to the answer.